# centos 6.2 can not load my shared library

Tags: linux

I compile my project on the Gentoo linux(x86_64) with 2.15 glibc.
Then i copy the *.so and out to centos server (6.2 x86_64) with glibc 2.12.
when i run command:

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ray/deploy/lib:/opt/glibc-2.15/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./deploy/proxy/scan
```

i got error :

```
./deploy/proxy/scan: error while loading shared libraries: libchecksum.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

what confusing me is that when i run command :

```
 sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ray/deploy/lib:/opt/glibc-2.15/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  ./deploy/proxy/scan
```

it works.
Does anybody know what goes wrong?
ldd info:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff207c1000)
    libchecksum.so => /home/ray/deploy/lib/libchecksum.so (0x00007fcccced2000)
    libportscan.so => /home/ray/deploy/lib/libportscan.so (0x00007fccccccc000)
    libc.so.6 => /opt/glibc-2.15/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcccc926000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcccd0d5000)
```

it shows that the *.so are found.

Thanks for your comments.
I try to compile on the server machine but the problem still exists.
I try to give 0777 to the libs and run scripts but still not work.

Comment: If it works under root and not under normal user, it will probably be permissions, no?

Comment: You cannot just copy shared object files across systems as you will run into conflicts.  Compile your project on CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

The setcap or sudo disable the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. So, it do not work.
You may use **rpath** option in gcc or just link the shared lib to /usr/lib.